# Выполнение viewDidLoad несколько раз

Tags: xcode, iphone

У меня вот такая задача, пользователь работает в FirstViewController (FVC) и в viewDidLoad FVC-а некий массив заполняется значениями, в частности картинками (ImageArray), пользователь работает с массивом и в нем соответственно меняются значения.
Потом пользователь переходит в SecondViewController (SVC), по модальному сегвею, что-то там делает и возвращается в FVC тоже по модальному сегвею, но тут проблема - опять перечитывается viewDidLoad FVC-а и массив ImageArray заполняется изначальными значениями, что не надо , нужно чтоб оставались старые значения, которые были до перехода в SVC.

Если не делать процедуру заполнения массива при возврате из SVC, т.е. в viewDidLoad FVC-а, то он (массив) становится пустым.

Подскажите как сохранить массив со старыми значениями?

Comment: Все верно, viewDidLoad может вызываться несколько раз. Можете описать, используете вы CoreData и может ли быть изменен массив картинок из SecondVC?

Comment: Как определить использование CoreData? (извиние но я еще новичек)
Массив не может быть изменен в SVC, с ним там ничего не делается, он вместе с данными остается в FVC.

Answer (score 1):

самое простое, что могу тут посоветовать: используйте паттерн Lazy Load:

объявляем проперти

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *myPhotos;
```

реализуем геттер:

```
 - (NSArray *)myPhotos {
     if (!_myPhotos) {
          _myPhotos = /* инициализация массива с данными */;
     }
     return _myPhotos;
}
```